# ons-scroller tag not working in Onsen UI

Tags: cordova, onsen-ui

I am using Onsen UI v1.0.4

Here is the code

```
<ons-page class="center">
<ons-navigator-toolbar left-button-icon="fa fa-lg fa-bars" on-left-button-click="ons.splitView.toggle();">
    </ons-navigator-toolbar>

<span style="font-size:20px; line-height:30px">
Some Content
    </span>

<ons-scroller>
1<br>
1<br>
1<br>
1<br>
1<br>
1<br>
1<br>
1<br>
1<br>
1<br>
1<br>
1<br>
1<br>
1<br>
1<br>
</ons-scroller>     
</ons-page>
```

Output:

[image]

Problem:

The text in `<span>` is missing and the content is not scrollable. Any ideas or suggestions to this problem? Thank You.

Update:

One thing I noticed was that, this problem occurs only when the  `ons-tabber` tag is used along with a `ons-scroller`. So posting my own answer with the cause and solition to the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is answered from my own experiance. So please correct me if I am wrong.

**Fact:**
The content area has to be clicked or touched to start scrolling it.

**Issue:**
When `ons-tabber` is added to a page with `ons-page` a new `div` of class `tab-bar-content` is inserted into the page. This div is transparent and resides just above the content area, stealing any click or touch the content is supposed to receive.

**Solution:**
Add the following style

```
.tab-bar-content{
z-index = -1;
}
```

**Explanation:**
This style sends the `tab-bar-content` div behind the content area, leaving it open to accept any clicks made on that area.

Answer (score 1):

ons-scroller directive occupies the full screen and your span tag was pushed away. So you need to locate your span into ons-scroller directive as following.

```
<ons-scroller>
    <span style="font-size:20px; line-height:30px">
        Some Content
    </span>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>
    1<br>        
    1<br>
</ons-scroller>
```

Onsen UI Team says " ons-scroller directive will not occupy the full screen on Onsen UI 1.1".